# indexeddb partial key search get next

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, indexeddb

Does the `indexeddb CursorWithValue` store what the next or prev record will be BEFORE I call `cursor.continue()`?  Can I look at the `IDBCursorWithValue` object and then store the pointer to the next record?

Is it possible to get the first record via a partial key, then get the next record ONLY when the user clicks for the next record without buffering a collection of the records in an array?

I understand I can use `cursor.continue()` to get all the matching records and store in an array.  I also understand that being asynchronous, if I just take the first matching record, and terminate my `onsuccess` function that call to the db is terminated and I'm fairly sure that I then lose the ability to link to the next record.

The following works and I can get one or all matching records of the partial key.  With the `\uffff` I basically get matching alpha and all greater records.

```
storeGet = indexTITLE.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.bound(x.value, x.value, '\uffff'), 'next');
```

This is all new to me, perhaps I'm looking at this all wrong.  Any advice is appreciated.  I've been reading every thread on here and github that I can, hoping someone else already was doing this with indexeddb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try and restate the problem:

> You've iterated a cursor part-way through a range. Now you want to stop and wait for user input before continuing. But the transaction will close, so you can't just continue on the click. What do you do instead?

First off: great question! This is tricky. You have a handful of different options.

In the simplest case, you have a unique index (or an object store) so there are no duplicate keys.

```
var currentKey = undefined;

// assumes you open a transaction and pass in the index to query
function getNextRecord(index, callback) {
  var range;
  if (currentKey === undefined) {
    range = null; // unbounded
  } else {
    range = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(currentKey, true); // exclusive
  }
  var request = index.openCursor(range);
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var cursor = request.result;
    if (!cursor) {
      // no records found/hit end of range
      callback();
      return;
    }
    // yay, found a record. remember the key for next time
    currentKey = cursor.key;
    callback(cursor.value);
  };
}
```

If you have a non-unique index it is more tricky since you need to store the index key and primary key, and there's no way to open the cursor right at that position. (See the feature request: https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/14) So you need to advance the cursor just past the previously seen key/primaryKey position:

```
var currentKey = undefined, primaryKey = undefined;

// assumes you open a transaction and pass in the index to query
function getNextRecord(index, callback) {
  var range;
  if (currentKey === undefined) {
    range = null; // unbounded
  } else {
    range = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(currentKey, true); // exclusive
  }
  var request = index.openCursor(range);
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var cursor = request.result;
    if (!cursor) {
      // no records found/hit end of range
      callback();
      return;
    }

    if (indexedDB.cmp(cursor.key, currentKey) === 0 &&
        indexedDB.cmp(cursor.primaryKey, primaryKey) <= 0) {
      // walk over duplicates until we are past where we were last time
      cursor.continue();
      return;
    }

    // yay, found a record. remember the keys for next time
    currentKey = cursor.key;
    primaryKey = cursor.primaryKey;
    callback(cursor.value);
  };
}
```

I'm assuming there's not an upper bound, e.g. we want all records in the index. You can replace the initialization of `range` as appropriate.

Comment: Basically i have multiple keys...  author, title, isbn, primary key, category.  I can lookup by primary key and edit fields, update records, delete records.  I can lookup partial keys and update and delete.  Like index = 'author' = 'Smi' and i get the first record starting with Smi....like Smitty.

Comment: your second example is exactly what i was presuming i was going to have to do.  I asked the question as I was hoping that any request.result would have a pointer to the next record of the valid search.  i'll test your example for now.  also, i guess i need to learn how to highlight code sections and format questions and answers.  also i can't even vote your answer up even though it is probably perfect... as i am a newbie.  i'll get back on my test of your answer...probably after the weekend.

Comment: i edited your near perfect example, i hope as a newbie it lets me edit.  no     IDBKeyRange.lower     , so i changed it to     IDBKeyRange.lowerBound

Comment: Oops, yeah, lowerBound() not lower(). Thanks for calling out the error!